REST. Make order request
I have two entities: Order and OrderItem. Should I use one or two routes for request that make an order?
One route:
POST /orders (also creates OrderItems)
Two routes:
POST /orders
POST /orderItems

Question is not clear, Please explain in brief.

This seems mostly opinion-based.  But, as an opinion, I don't see why we'd ever need to create "order items" outside the context of creating or updating an order.  This seems like a single request to me.

Use Just a single route which contains all the orderlist details, something like this
{
  "customerId": 123,
  "orderDate": "2024-09-23",
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 10.99
    },
    {
      "productId": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 20.49
    }
  ]
}

this will make sure that order and its items are created together in one transaction

this defies the whole purpose of rest, making this request transactional, which creates another set of problems. There is no atomicity here, if you want to make it transactional, then create a /transaction order post the body of each independent request and return the status codes for each one of them, like the json below

[
{
"uri": "https://api.example.com/orders",
"verb": "POST",
"body": {
"customerId": 123,
"orderDate": "2024-09-23",
"orderItems": [
{
"productId": 1,
"quantity": 2,
"price": 10.99
}
]
}
},
{
"uri": "https://api.example.com/orders",
"verb": "POST",
"body": {
"customerId": 123,
"orderDate": "2024-09-23",
"orderItems": [
{
"productId": 2,
"quantity": 1,
"price": 20.49
}
]
}
}
]

It all depends on your specific requirements & scenarios.

Go for one route, if you want atomicity and consistency between order & OrderItems (if you want to guarantee that both the order and items are created together).
If you want more flexibility, go with two routes, which allows you to create order first & later associate the items with the order.
You may need to create workflow to ensure the consistency.
The second approach makes your API more modular.

